# How to trigger an Asp.net application based on update in the database?

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, web-services

I have a button created on a webpage in ASP, C# which on click extracts data from the database and makes a request to the web service based on the data extracted and then displays the result on another web page. I have a hardware which reads the data from an ID and writes the data into the database.
The same database is refereed by both the application i.e. one application writes the data into database and another application reads the data and make the request to the web service.

The action for making the request to the web service starts when user clicks the button on the webpage. I want this event to be happen automatically like when the hardware read the ID data and writes the data into the database the other application should automatically read it and should make the request to the web service to display the response.

Is there is way in which I should create an application which is constantly listening from the database for any changes or update and gets triggered when a update is made to the database for example in my case the insert of a new record in the table.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using SQL Server you can use [SqlDependency](http://msdn.microsoft.com/tr-tr/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldependency.aspx) to subscribe to changes.

[Check this link for more information](http://techbrij.com/database-change-notifications-asp-net-signalr-sqldependency)